# Is it safe to delete CMakeCache.txt before each incremental build?

Tags: cmake

My incremental CI builds frequently get:

```
##[error]CMake Error: Target xxx has dependency information when it shouldn't.
##[error]Your cache is probably stale. Please remove the entry xxx_LIB_DEPENDS from the cache.
```

Is it safe to delete the cache file before each build?
Will most build binaries be still *up to date*, or will this trigger a full rebuild?

Comment: Easy enough to test? The binaries should be fine, you won't have to rebuild them but you will regenerate the build files.

Comment: Sure, i testet it. Seems to work, also the binaries are still up to date. I just want confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Someone answered here, but it was removed. So i answer it myself with a link to this question in the [CMake forums](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/is-it-safe-to-delete-cmakecache-txt-before-each-incremental-build/1279/2?u=kuga2):

> if you delete CMakeCache.txt before each build you must make sure to
>   configure and generate cmake. Without it is not “safe” because the
>   cached variables are missing in the next build.
>
> Deleting CMakeCache.txt should not affect any binaries, a full rebuild
>   is not triggered. Otherwise you might have a local variable passed on
>   before being cached which then leads to inconsistent runs.
>
> The regeneration of the project can trigger rebuilds if the
>   configuration is different to the previous one.

Thanks @hex